# Which values does Facebook accept as 'border_color'?

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-iframe

I'm trying to customize an iframe Facebook like box but I can't figure out which color hex codes are recognized by Facebook for the border_color attribute. The [official reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) is not so detailed on this topic.

I also didn't find how i have to specify the color in the iframe src url. It seems `border_color:orange` works, but `border_color:#DF9308` or `border_color:DF9308` don't.
Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put quotes, like `border_color="#FF0000"`. For me it works fine like this.

EDIT:
In iframe mode, be sure to encode the output. `border_color=%23FF0000`. %23 instead of #, because it’s a big URL.